# School and subject

Tags: prepositions

Is the next sentence right or if it's not how can we rewrite it?

> Do you remember the school and the subject you were interested in at?

What if we turn it:

> Do you remember the subject and the school you were interested in at?

Or it should already be "at in"?

> Do you remember the subject and the school you were interested at in?

Comment: None of those are right, and it's hard to work out what you mean. Can you describe what you are trying to convey by using several simpler sentences, perhaps?

Comment: It's like "Do you remember the school you were at and the subject you were intersted in at the school?" But it's just all together

Comment: Most people are interested in more than one subject at school. Do you mean "most interested"?

Comment: No, it's a combination of 2 sentences.
A different example: 1) Do you remember the shop you were in? 2) Do you remember the beer bottle you were looking at? And all together 3) Do you remember the shop and the beer bottle you were in(shop) looking at(the bottle).
If this kind of sentences doesn't exist in English - fine, I just don't know if it's possible:)

Comment: You could say "do you remember the subject you were interested in, and the school you were at at the time?". You could say "the school you were at when you were interested in it", but that seems semantically odd. You could say "the school you were interested in it at", which seems the nearest to what you are asking for, but it's clunky. But you still have to specify "subject you were interested in" separately.

Comment: But anyway I cna't combine them. These parts shoould be separated from each other. Their prepositions (in and at) can't go one after another.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix the two prepositions together like that. Each part of the conjunction needs to have its own preposition (and prepositional phrase).

It should be rephrased in a way like this:

> Do you remember the school you were at and the subject you were interested in?